# Number of matrices giving even row and column sum

Tags: combinatorics

> Count the number $n\times n$ matrices such that every row and column sum to an even number. Each element is either $0$ or $1$.

I know for a there are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. This gives $2^{n-1}$ subsets that have an even sum. But I don't know how to continue so that the columns are even as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is a special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/155057/), but I'm unsure about closing because the wording is quite different.

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, voting to close.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, since there’s no reasonable presumption that someone asking this question would even understand the language of the earlier question. However, the accepted answer to the earlier question is usable here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose that the element in the $i$th row $j$th column is $a_{ij}\in\{0,1\},\,i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Pick some arbitrary $a_{ij},\,i,j,\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, i.e. you pick $(n-1)^2$ entries of your matrix, starting from row $1$ to row $n-1$ and column $1$ to column $n-1$. Given these you may form a unique $n \times n$ matrix such that every row and column sum to an even number (by specifying the entries in the $n$th column and the $n$th row) (How?). The answer will be $2^{(n-1)^2}$.